# How can I run Kotlin-Script (.kts) files from within Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

I noticed that IntelliJ can parse `.kts` files as Kotlin and the code editor picks them up as free-floating Kotlin files. You are also able to run the script in IntelliJ as you would a Kotlin file with a main method. The script executes from top to bottom.

This form is PERFECT for the project I'm working on, if only I knew an easy way to use them from within Java or Kotlin.

What's the idiomatic way to "run" these scripts from Java or Kotlin?

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/cypressious/KotlinW. Basically you invoke the compiler with the -script parameter.

Comment: @KirillRakhman Thank you, but would this not have performance implications? You also wouldn't be able to reference functions, classes and more from within Kotlin/Java.

Comment: If this doesn't exist, would it be possible to implement by generating bytecode of a class with the file's name and a function like `run` that would house the content?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281513/355438

Comment: See Kotlin scripting related [roadmap issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49511).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Note that script files support in Kotlin is still pretty much experimental. This is an undocumented feature which we're still in the process of designing. What's working today may change, break or disappear tomorrow.

That said, currently there are two ways to invoke a script. You can use the command line compiler:

```
kotlinc -script foo.kts <args>
```

Or you can invoke the script directly from IntelliJ IDEA, by right-clicking in the editor or in the project view on a .kts file and selecting "Run ...":

[image: Run .kts from IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Thanks for the official heads up. I might work on something to generate proper bytecode for these scripts to make executing them in Java or Kotlin a breeze.

Comment: @Alexander any news on scripting with kotlin in runtime apps? We'd like to replace groovy runtime scripts with kotlin if possible :)

Comment: @Dodge running Kotlin scripts at runtime by the means of JSR 223 (Java scripting engines API) is currently work in progress. You can find an example of what can be achieved today at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example. I'll update my answer as soon as it's implemented and properly documented.

Answer (score 13):

### KtsRunner

I've published a simple library that let's you run scripts from regular Kotlin programs.

https://github.com/s1monw1/KtsRunner

### Example

1. The example class

   ```
   data class ClassFromScript(val x: String)
   ```
2. The `.kts` file

   ```
   import de.swirtz.ktsrunner.objectloader.ClassFromScript

   ClassFromScript("I was created in kts")
   ```
3. The code to load the class

   ```
   val scriptReader =  Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("path/classDeclaration.kts"))
   val loadedObj: ClassFromScript = KtsObjectLoader().load<ClassFromScript>(scriptReader)
   println(loadedObj.x) // >> I was created in kts
   ```

As shown, the `KtsObjectLoader` class can be used for executing a `.kts` script and return its result. The example shows a script that creates an instance of the `ClassFromScript` type that is loaded via `KtsObjectLoader` and then processed in the regular program.

Answer (score 12):

As of 2020 ([Kotlin 1.3.70](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-3-70-released/)), you can just use the straightforward

```sh
kotlin script.main.kts
```

Note that using the file extension `.main.kts` instead of `.kts` [seems to be important](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67375712/2111778).

Note that for me this does **not** seem to run the `main()` function if defined, I had to add a manual call to `main()` at the top level.

One of the advantages of Kotlin script is the ability to declare code and dependencies inside a single file (with `@file:DependsOn`, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67392820/2111778))

Comment: If I recall correctly, the code in a `.main.kts` file is effectively embedded inside a main function that is defined outside of the file (it probably comes from the implicit `kotlin-main-kts` dependency?). So there's always a main function defined, you just cannot see it. Which makes sense, because it's meant to be a script. If you could define your own main function, it would be an executable program, rather than a script, I think.

Comment: Note that it's set up in a way that allows you to define your own script runners. So you could make a script runner that takes `.myownthing.kts` files, for which you can determine what is implicitly in scope and how it's executed. For example, if you've created your own kotlin-based DSL, your `.myownthing.kts` runner could ensure that the compile-time and runtime dependencies for that DSL are always present for `.myownthing.kts` files, so that your users can directly use your DSL in their scripts. That's my understanding, at least. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: The "seems to be important" part was the piece I was missing and finally brought an end to my googling. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

early 2020ies [kscript](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript) that you find at https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript
seems to be the most convenient and well supported way to go ...

Answer (score 0):

[jgo](https://github.com/scijava/jgo) can fetch and run code from Maven repositories, so can be used to invoke
https://github.com/scijava/scijava-common and https://github.com/scripting-kotlin to execute a local `Foo.kt` like so:

```
jgo --repository scijava.public=maven.scijava.org/content/groups/public org.scijava:scijava-common:@ScriptREPL+org.scijava:scripting-kotlin Foo.kt
```

If no `Foo.kt` is provided, it launches a Kotlin REPL.