# Can I run kotlin as script with Java Scripting API

Tags: java, scripting, kotlin

I want to run kotlin code as script from java with [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) similar to this for javascript:

```
import javax.script.*;
public class EvalScript {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a script engine manager
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        // create a JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        // evaluate JavaScript code from String
        engine.eval("print('Hello, World')");
    }
}
```

or with similar APIs like this.

Comment: I'm sure you *could*, but why? The point of Kotlin is that it compiles to JVM bytecode.

Comment: I want to use it for load kotlin [Type-Safe Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) dsl or something like this in runtime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's possible starting from the Kotlin 1.1: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support

[KEEP-75](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md#using-jsr-223-javaxscript-api) has an example of the JSR-223 API call:

> ```
> val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("main.kts")!!
> engine.eval("""
> @file:DependsOn("junit:junit:4.11")
>
> org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(true)
>
> println("Hello, World!")
> """)
> ```

Configuration below adds Kotlin scripts engine to my Kotlin 1.2 project:

- `META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` file with the content from the https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory
- 2 libraries:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-script-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-script-util</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Update:**
Starting from Kotlin 1.2.20 `kotlin-script-util` doesn't depend on `kotlin-compiler` explicitly (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17561). So one more module should be provided (as of the [build file in example project](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/examples/kotlin-jsr223-local-example/build.gradle.kts)):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-compiler-embeddable</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin support for the Java Scripting API is [planned](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7880), but as of version 1.0.3 is not available yet. For the mean time, you can try to use an existing [open-source implementation](https://github.com/xafero/dynkt).