# .kts script in a Gradle project

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin Gradle project.

If I create a `.kts` file it runs in InteliJ alright *except* when it is in the `/src/main/kotlin` folder.

IDEA highlights the whole file in red.
Gradle throws out compilation exception.
The exception is

```
...src/main/kotlin/test.kts: (3, 1): Cannot access script base class 'kotlin.script.templates.standard.ScriptTemplateWithArgs'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`.
```

What is the problem?

My `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.0-rc-131'
}

group 'kotlin.tutorials.coroutines'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven {     url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
}

ext.ktor_version = '1.0.0-alpha-1'
ext.coroutines_version = '0.30.2-eap13'

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"

    //KTOR features
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-jackson:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-auth-jwt:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-freemarker:$ktor_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"
}

compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
```

Comment: why would you want to put a kts file there? Source files are still just kt files

Comment: I need some classes and I need some scripts to demonstrate how to use those classes. That's why it would be most convenient to put them together.

Answer (score 2):

`.kts` files should go to the `src/main/resources` folder since `src/main/kotlin` is for `.kt` files.

Scripts are a completely different animal in this sense, and you should use something like [KtsRunner](https://github.com/s1monw1/KtsRunner) to execute them.

Related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686957/can-i-run-kotlin-as-script-with-java-scripting-api/48281513#48281513).

If you just want to use scripts from IDEA, then you should use [Scratch files](https://youtu.be/PsaFVLr8t4E?t=1565) which are supported out of the box.

Comment: Note that I want to run this script from InteliJ, not from another program. Your answer is for another problem. I'll update the question.

Comment: Yes, scratch files is what I want. The problem is that I need them 1) to be in a folder hierarchy 2) to be in the project under Git.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem, but I still wish to get REPL support similar to the scratch files. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I think this is a `xor` for you. You either use the scratch files, or use `.kts` files from the `resources` folder with a script runner I'm afraid.

Comment: You were correct, JB confirmed that this feature is not yet available. You can vote on this ticket if you want https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27542

Answer (score 2):

The solution turned out to be very straight forward.

The compiler could not find utility classes that are usually added to any Kotlin script classpath. Adding one dependency to my `build.gradle` fixed it:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm"
}
```

#### P.S.

I created 2 tickets to improve Kotlin script support in InteliJ:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27542
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27544

If you care about those features, please vote them up!