# Kotlin integration in Java Code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

**Example:**
In C-code it is possible to call parts of assembler code, like:

```
int main()
{
   //... stuff
   __asm
   {
      lea ebx, hal
      mov ecx, [ebx]hal.same_name ;
      mov esi, [ebx].weasel       ;
   }
   // .. further stuff
   return 0;
}
```

**Is such a code integration possible for Kotlin code in Java (*.java) files?**

(I am not talkin about JNI or C/C++ in Java!) 
I would like to extend already existing (AndroidStudio-) Java-Source-Code with Kotlin language.

```
//.. this is *.java file
public class MyAlreadyExistingJavaClass {

private int memberVar;

public MyAlreadyExistingJavaClass()
{

}

// this is Kotlin within *.java file
// extend this Java file with this constuctor in KOTLIN ?
// would make above default constructor unneccessary.
class MyAlreadyExistingJavaClass(number: Int = 0)
{
  memberVar = number;
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java does not provide any syntax for including snippets of code in Kotlin or any other language into a Java file. However, this is not necessary to accomplish your task. You can simply define the constructor you need as a factory function in a separate Kotlin file:

```
fun MyAlreadyExistingJavaClass() = MyAlreadyExistingJavaClass(0)
```

If you want to define a new method, rather than a constructor, you can use [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am a Groovy developer, not a Kotlin developer, but it looks like Kotlin [provides a scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974039/how-can-i-run-kotlin-script-kts-files-from-within-kotlin-java) API. Groovy, JavaScript and JRuby can all be called from within a Java class using the standard Java ScriptEngine API. You would want something like that to approximate inlining Kotlin within a Java class. I say approximate because it wouldn't be run directly like that assembly example, but would be passed through a ScriptEngine-compliant Kotlin implementation.

Comment: Whoever voted my comment down, why don't you provide a better response. You should know damn well that Java cannot in-line Kotlin code like that and expect it to compile and that this is closest approach to getting that the Java compiler supports.