# How do i run code given/taken by the user in python

Tags: python, kotlin, exec

I am pretty new to Kotlin, i am trying to make a project in Kotlin that executes code taken by the user.
I have used `exec()` in python to execute code but I don't know how to use that either, please help me if you know python and Kotlin please help
Any help will be very much appreciated!!
Thanks

EDIT:here is some more info.. i am a newbie in Kotlin
i need help with some commands which are like exec in python
i am making a program to run python commands in a Kotlin program
this is experimental..
forgive me as i am a newbie to Stackoverflow..
thanks..

Comment: Please provide an example of the code that you tried.

Comment: If you are writing anything other then a development tool running user code might raise serious questions about seurity. I hope you have considered that.

Comment: Klaus D. I have prepared a few checking barriers using if statements which will raise a error if it is not the function i expected.. i have included a guide to ... P.S i am creating a python interpreter/compiler type thing in a python interpreter

Comment: Leo, i have not yet started my code i have made the flow chart logic for my program till now... I needed a code for executing code from the user in Kotlin, python, or any other language i am ok with c languages too

Comment: You may want to execute kotlin scripts rather than kotlin files https://kotlinexpertise.com/run-kotlin-scripts-from-kotlin-programs/ or https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/quick-run.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974039/how-can-i-run-kotlin-script-kts-files-from-within-kotlin-java these resources may help you.

Comment: I can do my project in most languages, if you know then help

Comment: Here is the exact thing with standard library might be faster https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#javaxscript-support here is examples of using jsr223 from standard library https://github.com/energister/kotlin-jsr223-example

Comment: is there any direct example, i am complete newbie to Kotlin, but if you can then tell me the answer in python or any c language as i am better with those

Comment: You can see the first link of my last comment pointing to the kotlin docs, that is straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea
You can get user inputs and save them on a file.
Then execute the saved file on the shell by importing 'os' library

```
import os

print("Enter any python commands!")
print("Enter 'run' to execute.")

user_inputs = ''

# Get user input until user enter 'run' phrase
while True:
    user_input = input('> ')
    if user_input == 'run': break
    user_inputs = user_inputs + "\r\n" + user_input

# save user input on a file
file = open("run.py", 'w')
file.writelines(user_inputs)
file.close()

# execute the code on terminal and get output, then display to the user
stream = os.popen('python run.py')
output = stream.read()

print("---------------------------------")
print(output)
```

Happy coding

Comment: Would i need to add python to my path?or no...

Comment: and will i need to make a run.py first... i haven't done File I/O in a long time sorry

Comment: It does not return any thing after i type run

Comment: with a few modifications i made it working! thanks alot

Comment: Good news dear friend,

Comment: you don't need to make run.py, source manages this. but there is one problem remain and this is, if the project run by two or more user at the same time, you have only one run.py
which overwrite by the last user.
you can use a random name or run_{userid}.py