# Only partial syntax highlighting in Kotlin script file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I opened a folder in Android Studio which contains a Kotlin script file (`.kts`). I configured a JDK as SDK in Project Structure (but I added no gradle files), and running the file as Kotlin script works fine. **However the syntax highlighting is only PARTIALLY working**, see below example (Linux Mint 19.3 and AS 4.1.3):

[image]

Some of the stuff missing:

- unused variable should be gray (`val unused`)
- extension methods (`.forEach`/`.to`/`.map`/`.toInt`/...) should be yellow and italic
- errors should be underlined red
- bad style such as extra spaces should be underlined yellow
- etc.

**What's even going on here? Is this some sort of "fallback" mode?**

Any way to use the "full" syntax highlighting from normal Android projects, so I can spot mistakes earlier?

For reference, **this is what it "should" look like** (pasted into a random Android project):

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-18438/Language-injection-doesn-t-work-in-build-gradle-kts) is related.

Comment: That doesn't seem related to me, can you explain?

Comment: So, forget about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Renaming the file to end in `*.main.kts` (`scriptname.main.kts`) enabled full highlighting for me!

Answer (score 1):

I get this type of issues from time to time with IntelliJ IDEA. I haven't found the reason why it happens, neither do I know the 100% working solution. But here are the options that usually help me solve it:

- Restart IDE
- Invalidating caches: <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Invalidate Caches...</kbd>
- Re-import the project. Remove the `.idea` folder and the `project.iml` file and try to import the project again.
- Update the IDE. Last time I had this issue, nothing helped but updating IDEA to 2021.1.

I hope some of these options will help.

Comment: Didn't help, not even with IDEA 2021.1. I guess editing lone script files without a gradle file / project around it just isn't supported?

Comment: I found a solution, see my other answer

Comment: Thanks for me removing the .idea folder did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Newer IDE versions have a **Repair IDE** (`File->Repair IDE`) option that did the trick for me. It takes you through a set of steps - reindexing, reopening the project, invalidate cache restart etc and tries to repair the IDE.

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to resolve the issue and tried a ton of solutions, but nothing helped me except this answer. Thank you! Important note: There are a few steps in the "Repair IDE" process, and my issue was resolved only in the last step.